# problem displaying cells in the tableview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am trying to display text in cell labels from information import into firebase. I currently have a problem, because the cells are formed, but I don't see the text information in the labels as shown in the pictures. can you tell me why i can't see the information and how to solve the problem.
Thanks.

```
 struct List {

var heure: String?
var date: String?
var location: String?
var event: String?
var title: String?
var comment: String?
    
    init(heure: String?, date: String?, location: String?, event: String?, title: String?, comment: String?) {
    self.heure = heure
    self.date = date
    self.location = location
    self.event = event
    self.title = title
    self.comment = comment
   }
}
```

class FourthViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

var activityList = [List]()

var ref : DatabaseReference!
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return 174
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activityList.count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PassViewController") as? PassViewController {
        vc.Heure?.text = activityList[indexPath.row].heure
        vc.Date?.text = activityList[indexPath.row].date
        vc.Location?.text = activityList[indexPath.row].location
        vc.Titre?.text = activityList[indexPath.row].title
        vc.Event?.text = activityList[indexPath.row].event
        vc.Comment?.text = activityList[indexPath.row].comment
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ActivityViewCell

        let test = activityList[indexPath.row]
        cell.Titre?.text = test.title
        cell.Heure?.text = test.heure
        cell.Date?.text = test.date
        cell.Location?.text = test.location
        cell.EventType?.text = test.event
        cell.comment?.text = test.comment

        return cell

        }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TableView.register(ActivityViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    TableView.dataSource = self
    TableView.delegate = self
    fetchActivityList()

       }


func fetchActivityList() {

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Activities").child(userID!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                let results = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                let titre = results?["Title"]
                let heure = results?["Heure"]
                let date = results?["Date"]
                let location = results?["Location"]
                let event = results?["EventType"]
                let comment = results?["Comment"]
        let myAct = List(heure: heure as! String?, date: date as! String?, location: location as! String?, event: event as! String?, title: titre as! String?, comment: comment as! String?)
                self.activityList.append(myAct)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.TableView!.reloadData()
                }
           })
        }
    }
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYIFk.png)

[Cell View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQmzN.png)

Comment: All your cells properties are optional. Are they `nil`? Like `cell.Titre`, is it nil? Where is defined your cell? In a xib? In Storyboard? If it's in a xib, you need to register the xib, not the class. When you do `let test = activityList[indexPath.row]`, could you check the values? You need to know if the issue in when fetching the data and retrieving it, or the UITableView part (ie display)...

Comment: The cell is defined in storyboard and all of values are nil

Comment: Which values? The cell labels, or the `activityList` properties?

Comment: all cell labels are nil

Comment: DId you connect the IBOutlets?

Comment: Yes, I connected the IBOutlets. I still have the problem. I put a breakpoint in fetchActivityList() and it tells me that all values ​​are nil

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should carefully debug whether you fetched your activityList successfully. Set a breakpoint into your `fetchActivityList()` and print your results.
Secondly, its important how you instantiate a cell: either in InterfaceBuilder or directly in code. You have to register a cell based on type of instantiation.

```
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)

@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Also, while registering a cell's class you may try to use `ActivityViewCell.self` instead of `ActivityViewCell.classForCoder()`

Futhermore, it would be great if you try to set breakpoints into

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

to figure out whats going on step by step.

I believe it would be great if you take a closer look to some codeStyle rules and try to keep them in future. For example, you may use Ray Wenderlich code style rules:
https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

And as another advice, try to get more information about architectural patterns (e.g. MV patterns). Thats the way to make your code clearer and objects relationships more intuitive.
I hope you're gonna figure out and resolve your issue! Have a nice day!

Comment: I put a breakpoint and In "cell" it tells me that all values ​​are nil and section = (Int) 0